# Add to link to URL in react in jquery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am creating a `<Link to=""></Link>` element in react and want to add the url when the page renders and this element turns into an anchor element. But, it doesn't seem to work. Below is the code :

`React code`

```
<Link to="" className="text-wrapper">
    <p>Custom page</p>
</Link>
```

`jQuery code`

```
$('#customId').find('a').attr('href', customUrl);
```

The URL is not redirecting anywhere. I have used Link because I do not want the page to load while navigating, I have used it at other places and that works fine. In other places, I have directly given values to the `<Link to=""></Link>` element like `<Link to="/about-us"></Link>`. But, when the url is being given using jquery, it doesn't work.

Comment: ID missing in link

Comment: The selector is for parent, anchor element is the child of the selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is, `<Link/>` is a react component not a `DOM` element. `jQuery` selector engine is designed to work with `DOM` elements.

**Solution**

Just do this

```
$.ajax('')
.done((data) => {
  ...
  this.setState({customUrl: 'your url here'})
})

<Link to={this.state.customUrl} className="text-wrapper">
    <p>Custom page</p>
</Link>
```

Comment: My custom URL is a result of an AJAX request that needs to be put there. How it can be done once the LINK component is rendered.

Comment: The ajax call and the component building are in different files.

Comment: @AbhishekDhanrajShahdeo If that's the case you need to pass the result as a `prop` to this component or use `redux`

Answer (score 0):

If the URL comes from AJAX request you probably should do that request in component lifecycle method like `componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount` (depending on your needs), store the result in React state (or Redux state) and then render it like

```
{this.state.url && (
  <Link to={this.state.url} className="text-wrapper">
    <p>Custom page</p>
  </Link>
)}
```